# PHP Navbar active class

Tags: php

This is the layout of my navigation menu. It works perfectly fine as it should. But I'd like to have

```
 <li class="active">
```

On the page that is currently active. How can I achieve that?

home.php:

```
<?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
```

navbar.php:

```
<li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=about">About</a></li>
//etc
```

index.php:

```
 $page = $_GET['page']; 
 if (!isset($page)) {
    include('home.php.php');
 }
 if ($page == "home") { 
    include('home.php.php');
 }
 if ($page == "about") { 
    include('about.php');
 }
 //etc
```

Comment: the `$_GET` in index.php is that necessary? or it's your approach to achieve what you are trying to achieve

Comment: please use a switch instead of an ifelseif jungle

Comment: `<li><a href="?page=home" <?php echo 'home'==$_GET['page']?' class="active" ':'' ?>>Home</a></li>`

Answer (score 5):

You could write an if statement for each link but this is a tidier method.

navbar.php

```
<?php

// using home as default, and not throwing a notice when $_GET['page'] isn't set
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page'] : 'home'); 

// create an array of pages and their titles
$pages = array(
    'home' => 'Home',
    'about' => 'About',
    // etc
);

// output each, checking for which is active
foreach ($pages as $pagestring => $text){
    $active = ($pagestring == $page? ' class="active"' : '');
    echo '<li' . $active . '><a href="?page=' . $pagestring . '">' . $text . '</a></li>';
}

?>
```

**If some pages have dropdowns** (not shown in the question) a little more work needs to be done... NB this wraps the whole thing with `<ul>` which doesn't seem to be in your navbar.php file.

```
$currentpage = (isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page'] : 'home'); 

$pages = array(
    'home' => 'Home', // just use a string for a simple link
    'about' => 'About',
    'cute' => array( // use an array for a dropdown
        'text' => 'Cute things', 
        'children' => array(
            'kittens' => 'Kittens',
            'puppies' => 'Puppies',
        )
    ),
    // etc, you can include children in children too
);

echo createLinksRecursive($pages, $currentpage);

function createLinksRecursive($array, $currentpage){
    $return = '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $pagestring => $linkarray){
        // we don't want to worry about whether it's a string or array more than once
        if (!is_array($linkarray)) $linkarray = array('text' => $linkarray);

        // check for active 
        $active = ($pagestring == $currentpage? ' class="active"' : '');

        // add the li and anchor element
        $return .=  '<li' . $active . '>
            <a href="?page=' . $pagestring . '">' . $linkarray['text'] . '</a>';

        // add children if there are any using the same function
        if (isset($linkarray['children'])){
            $return .= createLinksRecursive($linkarray['children'], $currentpage);
        }

        // close that li
        $return .= '</li>';
    }    

    // close the ul and return
    $return .= '</ul>';
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Okay this is wonderful, I appreciate you for helping me! If it's not much more trouble; how would this method work with a dropdown-menu?

Comment: I've added that anyway

Comment: I didn't think so much more work would have needed to be done - However, I am extremely grateful!! Thank you so much Popnoodles. (:

Comment: You could have just added a condition in each link, but that's not how we like to work.

Comment: Due to the stucture of my website I had to make a few adjustments, please let me know if there is an easier way.Changed to to get the correct page.

`$currentpage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` Edited the link and condition on active to allow for the .php at the end of the url.`$active = ($pagestring . '.php' == $currentpage ? ' class="active"' : '');<a href="' . $pagestring . '.php">'`